# BufferedWriter is acting strange

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am trying to make a game with a working highscore mechanism and I am using java.io.BufferedWriter to write to a highscore file. I don't have an encryption on the highscore and I am using Slick2D and LWJGL for rendering and user input. The program executes this code:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("res/gabjaphou.txt");

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

writer.write(score); // score is an int value

writer.close(); // gotta save m'resources! lol
```

I open the text file generated by this and all it reads is a question mark. I don't know why this happens, and I used other code from another project I was making and I had no problem with that... Does anyone know why? This is really annoying! :C

Comment: What is the possible value of `score`?

Comment: *"This is really annoying! :C"* - yea, bugs in your code can be really annoying like that :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BufferedWriter.write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) is meant to write a single charecter, not a integer.

> `public void write(int c)`
>            `throws IOException`
>
> Writes a single character.
>
> **Overrides**: write in class Writer
> **Parameters:** `c` - `int` specifying a character to be written
> **Throws:** `IOException` - If an I/O error occurs

Try

```
writer.write(String.valueOf(score));
```

Answer (score 4):

Please use `writer.write(String.valueOf(score));` otherwise it [writes `score` as a character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28int%29).
See the documentation:

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

What you want to use is [`Writer.write(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28java.lang.String%29); convert `score` to a `String` using `String.valueOf` or `Integer.toString`.

```
writer.write(String.valueOf(score));
```

Comment: (See comments from Nivas below)

Comment: @TehHippo I originally commented on the question and then posted the answer here before Nivas.

Comment: @SuperCheezGi since you appear newer here, please don't forget to mark the answer [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped most in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedWriter` is attempting to write a series of bytes to the file, not numbers.  A number is still a character.

Consider using `FileWriter` instead, and something as simple as:
`fileWriter.write(Integer.toString(score))`   Write takes a string here, but the output should be the same.

Comment: You need to convert `score` to a `String`, otherwise you're still calling `write(int)`.

Comment: Correct; in this instance Java wouldn't just handle it.  Fixed and noted, thanks ;)