# Java: Bank simulation: Write to file, erased text/writing symbols

Tags: java, file, console-application, filewriter, bufferedwriter

As a way to learn java, I attempted to write something simulating a bank(adding or removing numbers). I succeeded in creating a file(if one does not exist already), and then read from it, but when I attempt to write to it, it fails. I started with FileWriter, where it just erased the text in the document(balance.txt). I then tried BufferedWriter, and it wrote to the document, but it was just symbols instead of actual text/numbers. I'm aware that I'm a newbie when it comes to coding, but is there a solution to this? Thank you.

```
if (choice.equals("ADD")){
            System.out.println("Currently selected: " + choice);
            //write to file
            try {
                String filePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programming\\projects\\java\\RandomStuff\\Bank\\balance.txt";
            //    System.out.println("How much would you like to add?");
            //    Scanner inputAdd = new Scanner(System.in);
            //    String balanceToAdd = inputAdd.nextLine();
            //    writeToFile.write(balanceToAdd);



                int balanceToAdd = 1;
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
                out.write(balanceToAdd);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Added: " + balanceToAdd);
            }   //try end
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error(line56): " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875815/bufferedwriter-is-acting-strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public FileWriter(String fileName,
boolean append)

I think you should use append to edit your file.

```
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath,true));
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it to work by changing out.write(balanceToAdd); to out.write(String.valueOf(balanceToAdd));